# call a navigation menu page on custom button click in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app

Is it possible to call a navigation menu url on the button click of a lightning component at all?

My Navigation menu right now, refers to standard 'My Cases' page. How do i call it? I tried below but its not the right way, it opens up the same page where the button exists

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            urlEvent.setParams({
              "url": "My Cases"
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
```

Comment: You can navigate to a list view using the [`force:navigateToList`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToList.htm) event. ps: the `force:navigateToUrl` event is not supposed to work like this. You have to put an url in the `url` parameter.

Comment: Thanks much!!! @Martin Lezer, it works with force:navigateToList...